# How rerender scene after setting active camera in Blender 2.6 using Python

Tags: python, camera, blender, scene

I have the following code in my Blender game:

```
if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.QKEY]:   
    bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects["Camera.Shoulder"]
```

My camera IS reset to 'Camera.Shoulder' but the view is not changed unless I exit and reenter a scene.  Is there a way to rerender the scene using the new active camera during the game without using a logic brick (I want everything in Python.)

Answer (score 1):

The correct code should be:

```
if bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.QKEY]:   
    bge.logic.getCurrentScene().active_camera  = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects["Camera.Player"]
```

bge is for game engine logic, don't know why bpy doesn't work.